# Android Things bundle - UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, android, android-things

I use a native library in my Android Things project. While using Android Studio to build and install an app on RPi3 with Android Things Dev preview 0.4.1 everything works fine. Even if I manually assemble release apk and install it through an adb install - it works as usual.
But if I create a new zip bundle and upload it to Android Things console, and then burn an SD card with newly created image, the UnsatisfiedLinkError is thrown on boot:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/oem/app/app.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/oem/lib/app, /system/fake-libs, /oem/app/app.apk!/lib/armeabi, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libspeech.so"
```

My app.apk contains /lib/armeabi directory with libspeech.so inside exactly. Did anybody have something similar with Android Things?

Comment: This is a known issue, and we are working on a fix internally. I see you've already filed a bug report. This will be the best place for you to track progress.

Comment: Same situation, all C++ libraries are missing, also Fabric library files and others files on my OTA apk.

Comment: On last Android Preview DP6 this issue does not resolved yet, :'(
@Devunwired know you any ETA for it? thank you

Comment: On last Android Developer Preview 7 this issue does not resolved yet..

Comment: I recently encountered such an issue. 'Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError' when I push OTA updates. @Devunwired Any solution for this? Using RPI3 AndroidThings 1.0.14

Comment: https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/apis/native

Answer (score 0):

With last version (dev preview 7) the issue sometimes happens, when you use the same `versionCode` and `versionName` on your new builds does not happen it, this is a provisional solution..