# Xamarin on Android Things via Console

Tags: android, xamarin, raspberry-pi, android-things

I have been struggling for days to get an app to run on Android Things via the console. If I run the standard image bundle on the Pi (3) and run via adb/debug it will run the app without issue. When I build for release and upload the bundle via Android Things console it won't boot, just a black screen.

I have connected via adb and dumped out the output from `adb logcat` and I can see that it is having problems finding `libmonodroid.so` but when I open the main.apk I can see in `lib/armeabi-v7a` the file `libmonodroid.so`.

The exception is:

```
12-13 17:13:02.297  1425  1425 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 17:13:02.297  1425  1425 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.myapp.tv_app, PID: 1425
12-13 17:13:02.297  1425  1425 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/oem/app/main.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/oem/lib/main, /oem/app/main.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libmonodroid.so"
12-13 17:13:02.297  1425  1425 E AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1011)
12-13 17:13:02.297  1425  1425 E AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1657)
12-13 17:13:02.297  1425  1425 E AndroidRuntime:     at mono.MonoPackageManager.LoadApplication(MonoPackageManager.java:34)
12-13 17:13:02.297  1425  1425 E AndroidRuntime:     at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:22)
12-13 17:13:02.297  1425  1425 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6239)
12-13 17:13:02.297  1425  1425 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5805)
12-13 17:13:02.297  1425  1425 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5722)
12-13 17:13:02.297  1425  1425 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
12-13 17:13:02.297  1425  1425 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
12-13 17:13:02.297  1425  1425 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
12-13 17:13:02.297  1425  1425 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
12-13 17:13:02.297  1425  1425 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
12-13 17:13:02.297  1425  1425 E AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-13 17:13:02.297  1425  1425 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
12-13 17:13:02.297  1425  1425 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807).
```

I have only the `armeabi-v7a` selected under the advanced settings and the `Use shared runtime` switch is off.

As I mentioned, I can see in the apk that the file is present.

Is there anything else I need to do to my configuration to make this work via the console build?

Comment: Is that the whole exception? It looks like there should be a few more lines with it. Can you include those? While you're at it, you should upload the `adb logcat` so we aren't guessing here.

Comment: Sorry, updated to include the full exception. The output from logcat is repeating that exception over and over. There are some other lines regarding network setup and Gcm but nothing else related to the APK in question

Comment: I think this answers my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46161998/android-things-bundle-unsatisfiedlinkerror

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with another library and I had to include all **Supported ABIs** under *Droid Project Options* -> *Android Build* -> *Configuration: Release* -> *Advanced*

[image]